# How to reference existing objects during NSCoding state-restoration

Tags: ios, nscoding, nscoder, state-restoration

I have a class that implements NSCoding and holds a reference to a UIView object...

```
class A: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var view: UIView!

    init(view: UIView) {
        super.init()
        commonInit(view)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit(/* <Need to pass the existing view somehow> */)
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        super.encodeWithCoder(aCoder)
    }
}
```

The `view` passed is a particular heavyweight custom view class that I don't need to serialise. There are many `A` objects and they all reference this same custom `UIView`. But during state restoration I need a reference to it in order to restore instances of `A`. The `view` instance already exists at the point I need it, and my custom UIViewController actually initiates the decoding sequence:

```
override func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
   // How to get self.customView to A.init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) where 
   // it is needed?
   let view = self.customView   
   self.a = coder.decodeObjectForKey("aKey") as! A
}
```

But how can I make the existing view available to `A.init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`?

Comment: Short answer is you can't.  You'll have to provide some sort of fix-up post serialization.

Comment: Dang, thought that might be the case, some kind of two-step init. All that would be needed would be for NSCoder to allow something like `setObjectReference(obj: AnyObject, forKey: String)`